# How to parallelize a for loop inside some_module.forward(some_input) (on the GPU)?

Tags: pytorch

Let's say I have a model (in pseudo-code, mostly):

```
class SomeLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, s):
        #init some layers etc
        self.N = s*s
    def forward(self, input_tensor):
        #intialize some variables
        some_results=[]
        for iter_i in range(self.N):
            # do independent operations on different parts of input_tensor
            # each operation is basically a copy of a subtensor of input_tensor
            # such that its size depends on iter_i
            # append_results to some_results
        return some_results
```

What is the correct way of parallelizing that sort of `for` loop? Currently I'm planing to write a small CUDA kernel for that and load that from python, but it feels a bit overkill, and I asssume there should be a simple way to do that although I haven't been able to find it in the documentation.

Comment: have you looked at [`unfold`](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.unfold)? it kind of facilitates "general purpose" sliding window operations. I'm not sure this matches the vague description you provided...

Comment: @Shai Thanks, I'll have a look. I apologize if that sounds vague, I'm just looking for a general way of parallelizing (simple) for loops similar to what you'd get with openmp in C++, if that makes any  sense.

Comment: I would guess that if you tell us the specific problem (e.g slow version with for loop) there are plenty of people here who are good at optimizing such things.